# What would Elm zip code example look like if it were getting back root of JSON?

Tags: elm

Hello I am struggling with getting the root of a JSON using Elm.
All of the examples show decoding a nested [{info here}].

What would the zip code example found on the Elm site look like if it was getting the root of the JSON? {"post code": "I want this"}.

What are the steps to http -> decode Json(one string "post code") -> To main output.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You may already have it but you need

```
http.get ("post code" := string) url
    |> Task.maybe
    |> Task.map ActionName
    |> Effects.task
```

I recently built a Json.Decode interpreter for testing Decode functions - see http://simonh1000.github.io/decoder

Comment: Thanks. How would this be displayed as html? I need an example showing something like object3 being displayed as html; like the zip code example but not using a List String.

Comment: To get to Html, your update function parses the Action and updates its model with the value attached to ActionName, and then your view function renders the model - https://github.com/evancz/elm-architecture-tutorial/

Comment: Great! Example five shows how to use JSON.at to get one element back.

Answer (score 0):

It took a while to find this.
But it would look like this [Japanese explanation of getting one element and turning into html](http://qiita.com/nobkz/items/56267f565e288278d865)